# windows install can't find hard drive after uninstalling ubuntu 12.04

Tags: partitioning, windows, system-installation, hard-drive

I have a dell xps gen 5, which I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and put VirtualBox on to have windows available.
It worked fine, till a "recommended update". VirtualBox no longer worked and Ubuntu kept barfing up `system problem detected` on every start.

I dropped a windows xp installation cd to put xp back on, but it the installer couldn't find a hard drive. I figured this might be due to the file system or something.

I used the Ubuntu live cd to access gparted and wiped the hard drive out, then I created a new partition table with an ntfs partition and a fat32 partition. XP still can't find a hard drive when I use the XP install cd. Ubuntu can see/format the drive just fine, so I know it's not a hardware or connection problem.

How do i get xp back on this machine?

---

Edit: This morning I tried using gparted again to wipe the hard drive and create new partition table, then did NOT create any partitions. To my knowledge XP setup can do the partitioning, so I thought that might work better, but I got the same error.

Comment: But we can not ask the questions you want to hear: if you use a windows installer to install windows Ubuntu is not in the picture. The formatting of the disc has nothing to do with installing an OS: the new one will simply not install unless the disk is formatted in an acceptible filesystem. This is a Windows installation problem.

Comment: I agree with Rinzwind; you should ask about this on a Windows forum. That said, chances are the stock Windows XP disc you're trying to use lacks drivers for your hard disk controller. This might be true even if the computer came with Windows XP pre-installed, because manufacturers sometimes ship hardware with additional drivers that don't come with the stock installation media, particularly when the computer was released after the OS in question.

Comment: thanks. i had assumed ubuntu changed something, that's why i went here. after your input, i did some searching and found this:
http://forums.techguy.org/hardware/1126148-looking-help-installing-windows-xp.html

posting here in case it helps anyone else. thanks again.